# Audio Alert in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio

I want to display multiple alert box as well as an audio alert when some value is violating. And  also need  an option to close that audio alert . I have done like this

```
  if( ($mark<=$minValue) ||  ($mark>= $maxValue))
  {          
 echo " <script> var audio = document.createElement('audio');
 document.body.appendChild(audio);
 audio.src = '/sounds-990-system-fault.mp3';
 setInterval(function(){audio.play();}, 5000);
 alert('Average student'); 
 </script>";
    }
```

But here I got alert box first and after pressing OK audio is come.I need audio come along with the alert box.And
How can I close that audio alert ?

Comment: by default alert is a stack process so execute one after other use any custom popup like jquery ui popup

Comment: please see my edited question. And can you suggest a link for doing it in jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work, as the code after the alert will be run once OK is clicked.

```
  if( ($mark<=$minValue) ||  ($mark>= $maxValue))
  {          
     echo " <script> var audio = document.createElement('audio');
       document.body.appendChild(audio);
       audio.src = '/sounds-990-system-fault.mp3';
       audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
         audio.play();
         alert('Average student'); 
         audio.pause();
       }, false);
     </script>";
    }
```

Comment: Hi, That's great. Now as in the code audio comes along with alert. But audio stops when alert box comes . I want to play the audio till clicking on OK button of alert box. Is it possible?